# Fat32 error on external hardrive

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive

I have an external drive - drive F - when trying to pull the drive up, it comes up with FAT32 System F Dirty....it will not acknowledge my F drive - does anyone have an idea as to how to fix this problem

Comment: what is the error exactly - can you take a screen shot?

Comment: Right click drive -> Properties -> Check for error

Answer (score 1):

Go to the command prompt and type:

`chkdsk f: /f`

This should scan and fix the majority of problems on the drive.